# HOw to access the hidden value set in cshtml from controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Can i have something like this in my cshtml

```
@Html.hiddenfor(model => model.name , "passname")
```

In controller :

i want to access this modal.name which will be having the value i set  i.e "passname"

Comment: Don't you have the model in the controller? Can't you just access model.name, directly?

Comment: ya but in my page i dont have a input field for name and i just want to pass a default text value to my modal .this is done to make sure that value is coming from page only

Comment: you just have to call directly in your controller like Model.PropertyName , it really doesnt matter whether its hidden or not..

Comment: so u just pass the default value in your view and use that in your controller the same way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1 - your model has to have this property that it can pass to HiddenFor. For example

class

```
class PageModel{
   public string HiddenFieldValue{get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

in cshtml

```
@model PageModel
...
@Html.hiddenfor(model => model.name, model.HiddenFieldValue)
```

in controller

```
public ViewResult MyPage(){
    return View(new PageModel(){
        HiddenFieldValue = "Hello World!";
    });
}
```

---

2nd way: pass in through [ViewBag/ViewData](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx).

in controller

```
public ViewResult MyPage(){
    ViewBag.HiddenFieldValue = "Hello World!";
    return View();
}
```

in cshtml

```
@model PageModel
...
@Html.hiddenfor(model => model.name, ViewBag.HiddenFieldValue)
```

Comment: Just going to comment: I interpreted the question as how can the controller control the value of a hidden text field. If this is wrong, then just ignore this post :)

Comment: ok. i got a varibale in my javascript which is written in my cshtml . i want the value of that varibale while i post the page . that is i want that variable value in my controller .can u help me out

Comment: Put that variable in a hidden field and post it to your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the hidden field will be send together with all the other POST data (if your form uses a POST).

So you can:

1. Add a property "passname" to the model that you use to retrieve the data.
2. Create an argument named "passname" on the action that handles the post.
3. Add a FormCollection to the argement (on the action that handles the post), and retrieve the value from there.
4. Get it from the Request using Request.Form["passname"] or event Request["passname"]

   ```
   // Example 1

   public class MyModel {
      // other properties

      public string passname { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyController : Controller {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel data) {
        }
   }

   // Example 2

   public class MyController : Controller {
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult MyAction(string passname) {
      }
   }

   // Example 3

   public class MyController : Controller {
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection data) {
           var passname = data["passname"];
      }
   }

   // Example 4

   public class MyController : Controller {
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult MyAction() {
           var passname = Request.Form["passname"];
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: ok.i got a varibale in my javascript which is written in my cshtml . i want the value of that varibale while i post the page . that is i want that variable value in my controller .can u help me out